# Daemon process not logging into custom log files

Tags: python, logging, daemon

I am creating a daemon process which monitors loads on database. The process is created using the reference of code at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731-creating-a-daemon-the-python-way/

What I am trying to do is:

1. Call the createDaemon() method defined in the function on above link.
2. Call the function monitor_load() after calling above mentioned function. This function is defined in the same script.

Inside monitor_load(), I call python logging module to log all information in a log file.

I understand that while creating daemon, the code is redirecting all STDOUT, STDIN, STDERR to /dev/null, but I do not want that to happen. I want all logging to happen properly from inside the daemon process.

Any idea how I can accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please note, I cannot use python-daemon module.

Comment: May I ask the reason?

Comment: Yes. The production environment does not allow me to install any utility which does not come with default python installation.

Comment: and you can't bundle it with your application using the tar.gz file from pypi?

Comment: Found out the solution. Just needed to close only STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR of parent process. The code was closing all.

Thanks for looking into it Benjamin.

Comment: Then please add this as an answer and accept it, so people don't have to see it in the "Unanswered" views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution. Just needed to close only STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR of parent process. The code was closing all. Thanks for looking into it Benjamin